# How to handle all the minification / uglify process

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, production, uglifyjs

I have a AngularJS application which I should deploy and I found that it is better to minify / uglify my javascript file for production.

I found different way to uglify my files like grunt for example.

But there is something I don't get...

I will minify/uglify those files then I will have a specific folder for those "production" files. *OK*

Then :

1. How should I use them in my `index.html` ?
2. How should I switch from  dev to prod ?
3. What should be the structure of my website folder ? Should I still contain the not-uglified files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I can explain it to you using gulp instead of grunt.

**How should I use them in my index.html ?**

You can put JS and CSS files in your html. In html we can specify comments saying which files need to be compiled together along with destination file using bower.

For example:-

```
<!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/angular-ui-router-anim-in-out/css/anim-in-out.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/video.js/dist/video-js.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/angular-tooltips/dist/angular-tooltips.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.css" />
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

Now if see the above css files are compiled into vendor.css while you run the gulp script. Now in gulp script you can provide the option for uglification and minification.

Similarly you can put js files also. Now this is how uglification and minification takes places.

```
gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(assets)
    .pipe($.if('*.js', $.uglify()))
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.minifyCss({
      compatibility: '*'
    })))
```

If you uglify/minify now you index.html has following:-

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/vendors.css" />
```

**How should I switch from dev to prod ?**

You can keep a nested JSON file and create individual elements for dev,prod and local and keep required settings here and use them in gulp while compiling the project.

```
{
  "dev": {
   //required keys
   },
  "prod" :{
  //required keys
}
```

**What should be the structure of my website folder ? Should I still contain the not-uglified files ?**

Your website structure can be as:-

- app

  - scripts
  - styles
  - fonts
  - index.html
- bower.json
- gulpfile.js

Comment: The index.html will automatically switched from minified/uglified files to normal files ?

Comment: Yeah, depends on environment. If u running on local then all ur normal files would be there, in production if specific uglify/minify option your files would be compiled, minified and put in a single file.

Comment: But how the references will be handle in the index.html ? How does it know when to reference the single file or when to reference all the files ?

Comment: I will take example of CSS to explain this.When you uglify/minify using gulp, you all css files are compiled into one css file. So your html technically contains only one CSS file now. I will update answer to make it more clear.

Comment: It is more clear now but I am still stuck with the index.html... After minify/uglify I cannot go back to all the references ? It is easier for debugging and development

Comment: This is done only on the production server, in local you server the files normally.

Comment: Okok I think that I start to understand ! I will try to use this on my future projects ! Thx you so much for making this clearer

Comment: Actually you are not solving Weedoze problem. I think the question is how you can you switch from: 

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.css" />

to the production index.html:

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/vendors.css" />

Comment: @ZanattMan i think i am.. Gulp does that..please read the answer once again :)

Answer (score 1):

another way is to use gulp-useref plugin, putting comments inside the html file to mark all js files and name the resulting bundle

in the html file

```
<!-- build:js bundle.js -->
<script src="js/jsfile1.js" ></script>
<script src="js/jsfile2.js" ></script>
<script src="js/jsfile3.js" ></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

in the gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('build', function(){
   gulp.src('app/*.html')
   .pipe(useref())
   .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

this will result a single minified js file `bundle.js` with proper reference in the html file